# How to transfer values from button POST request to BootStrap Modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a webpage which will update the database with a button click and the modal form will appear for the user to fill in. However, im having difficulties extracting the $_GET request submitted upon clicking the button. Source code for button is as follows :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action ="upload.php">

    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" formmethod="get" formaction="upload.php?item='.$row["fname"].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>Update</a>
</form>
```

When i try to do a print_r on the modal after clicking "Update" , there is no values. Is there a way to transfer $row["fname"] into the Bootstrap Modal ? Source code for modal is as follows :

```
        <div class="modal-body">
      <?php 
                print_r($_GET);             
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posted using POST

```
... method="post" ...
```

change it to

```
... method="get" ...
```

other wise, use `$_POST[]` instead of `$_GET[]`

Comment: sorry. was a typo my mistake. I wrapped them all in a <form> stating method as post. rectified

Comment: btw, i tried with the changes u mentioned but it still does not work